# Способы создания деформированных фигур на css

Tags: html, css, clip-path

Всем привет! Есть задача замутить что то вроде такой фигуры:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не однократно натыкался на такие но все никак не доходили руки разобраться как их делать. Случайно нашел вот такой сайт https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ где можно генерировать clip-path, но в таком случае нельзя коректно скруглить углы, потому что clip-path просто "обрезает" блок давая ему искривленный вид, а не деформирует сам блок. В итоге у меня вышло что то типо этого

```css
.col-lg-2 {
    padding: 20px;
}
#test-circle6 {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #AC55D9;
    clip-path: polygon(0 10%, 100% 0, 100% 88%, 0% 100%);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div id="test-circle6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Может знаете какие либо способы, или сторонние сайты/ресурсы для генерации подобных фигур? Ну или обьясните как правильно их делать? Спасибо за ранее!

Comment: наверно тут transform skew rotate достаточно будет + persective

Answer (score 4):

Развлекайтесь...

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  perspective: 200px;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: magenta;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transform: rotate3d(2, -1, 0, 25deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: «Что-то вроде» действительно вышло, но, кажется, повернуть прямоугольник так, чтобы получить результат в точности как на картинке из вопроса, таким способом всё-таки не получится (если мой глазомер меня не обманывает)

Comment: @andreymal, вопрос подбора коэффициентов и перспективы на мой взгляд.

Comment: Вот я о том и говорю, что для прямоугольника коэффициенты скорее всего не получится подобрать

Comment: @andreymal, возможность задать несколько трансформаций разного типа никто не отменял. было бы терпение.

Comment: Тогда уж становится проще просто в svg путь отрисовать)

Comment: @andreymal ну, вас же под дулом пистолета никто не держит, делайте как вам проще. )